# Python Webscraping But Need to Login First

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm new at Python and wanted to Webscrape this Website for a Discord Bot:
https://statbot.net/dashboard/757202345950969966/voice
But you need to Login first so you are coming to the right site.

Can i maybe skip that then I open the browser manually.
Cause the Login cannot be automated.

Sry for my English, thanks for answers.

Comment: What libarys are you using for webscrape?

Comment: BeautifulSoup and requests

Comment: İ dont think you can automate login with bs4 and requests but you can automate it with selenium libary.

Comment: yeah i tried that but i need to go through a Captcha login and that cannot be automated. i think

Comment: i dont know how to solve your problem

Comment: ah no problem but thanks